# Raising a matrix to the nth power

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a matrix by itself, n times

```
import numpy as np
fil1=3
col1=2

mat1 = random.random((fil1,col1))
mat3 = np.zeros((fil1,col1))
pot = 3
print('Matriz A:\n',mat1) 
for r in range(0,fil1):
    for c in range (0,col1):
        mat3[r,c]=mat1[r,c]*mat1[r,c]
print('Pot:\n',mat3)
```

How could I implement it by multiplying the same matrix by n times ??

```
#Example Mat1^2 = 
[ 1  2  3     [ 1  2  3       [ 1  2  3       [ 30  36  42 
  4  5  6   =   4  5  6    *    4  5  6     =   66  81  96
  7  8  9 ]     7  8  9 ]       7  8  9 ]       102 126 150 ]
```

Comment: What is your question? You don't need the loops. You can vectorize it by just doing `mat1**pot`

Comment: I lost, but I'm trying to learn matrices and I need to apply the loop to multiply the matrix N times without using ** @RafaelC

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between matrix multiplication, `M @ M` in python, and element-wise multiplication, `M * M`.

Comment: Btw. the generic (not the optimal in this case) way of chaining a binary operator would be `functools.reduce`. For example matrix multiply 5 copies of `M`: `functools.reduce(operator.matmul, 5*[M])`.

Comment: But if you want to multiply the same matrix N times, would it also work? @PaulPanzer

Comment: Yes, to verify, compare `M@M@M@M@M` to `functools.reduce(operator.matmul, 5*[M])`.

Comment: Using a generator could increase performance: `reduce(matmul, (M for __ in range(5)))`.

Comment: @a_guest I ran a quick and unscientific test and on my laptop it's actually slower. I'm getting `5*(M,) < 5*[M] < itertools.repeat(M, 5) < (M for _ in range(5))`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own recursive function using [**`numpy.matmul`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

def matrixMul(a, n):
    if(n <= 1):
        return a
    else:
        return np.matmul(matrixMul(a, n-1), a)

print(matrixMul(a, 4))
```

Non recursive way using **for-loop**:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

def matrixMul(a, n):
    if(n == 1):
        return a
    else:
            tempArr = a;
            for i in range(1, n-1):
                tempArr = np.matmul(a, tempArr)
            return tempArr

print(matrixMul(a, 4))
```

Comment: Great, how could I do it with For?